# CA1726: FxCop Forbidden Word: Flags

Tags: c#, coding-style, fxcop, rules

*someone* wants me to make other people's code compliant to some FxCop ruleset which includes rule [CA1726:Use preferred terms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182258%28v=VS.100%29). Most of the terms/replacements are all right and I can understand that one has to decide on one single way to name things.

However, what's the deal with the term 'flags'? Can anyone explain to me why I shall not use this name? (before I go and complain about it at my boss ;) )

Say, I have a data object which has a member of class 'flags' which bundles a large number of properties that define how to handle the data object. How else would you call this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the book *Framework Design Guidelines*, which is what FxCop is based on, the authors say that using `Flag` or `Flags` is a bad idea.  Their alternative suggestion is that when naming enumerations that you use a singular name for standard enums and a plural name for bit field (flags) enums.

For example if you wanted to create an enum listing different visibilities then you would name it `Visibilities` instead of `VisibilityFlags` or `Visibility`:

```
[Flags]
public enum Visibilities {
   Public,
   Private
}
```

The only items considered flags in .NET by the authors are these bitfield enumerations due to the keyword `Flags` attribute.

Comment: I'm using a BitArray, to represent... a set of flags. Putting 'flags' in the name seems quite natural. This seems like a bit of a draconian rule to me.

Comment: Reviving an old Q&A - I am running into this issue because the business really uses the term "flag" and I want to represent that in the domain model. I am sure that book refers to flag as a bad idea when it comes to the programming concept of an on/off field, and that is fine. But implementing this rule in FXCop such that *any* use of flag is considered obsolete is an even worse idea IMHO - just look at google and find that the term "flag" is still in use for many things, e.g. country flags, or flagging a post.

Comment: Ironically, Stackoverflow *has* a concept of flagging posts; imagining how the SO team is forced to use a term different from "flag" for representing post flags in their domain model just to satisfy FXCop is a bit worrying...

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the property should be named aptly, and that the term `Flags` characterises the property rather than describing it.

> Flag or Flags | There is no replacement term. Do not use.

For instance, `Flags` is generally used with enumerations (that are decorated with the appropriate attribute) and we certainly don't need to explicitly state so within the name / identifier of a property:

```
[Flags]
enum StorageMode
{
    None = 0,
    Next = 1,
    ...
    Last = 32
}

class StorableItem
{
    public StorageMode StorageMode { get; set; }
}
```

But, in your case, I get the feeling that whatever is named, or contains within its name, `Flags`, isn't actually a set of flags in the above sense - which just brings up another reason as to why to avoid it.

Comment: It's a bit like Hungarian notation, except it's a suffix, and it's a word instead of a couple of cryptic letters.